# changing brightness in for loop only accepts first argument

Tags: python, opencv, wmi

I am analyzing a video on very low framerate.
If certain things in the video match my requirements then the count goes up by 1
Once the count reaches 3 it will turn the screen brightness down, then up again, and then back to the default (startbrightness) setting.

I am getting the current screen brightness like this at the beginning:

```
objWMI = GetObject('winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\WMI').InstancesOf('WmiMonitorBrightness')
for obj in objWMI:
    startpointbrightness = obj.CurrentBrightness
print(startpointbrightness)
```

My loop is defined like this (to reduce frame rate):

```
frame_rate = 0.3
prev = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
framerate = cap.get(5)
count = 0

while True:

# Grab a single frame of video every frame-rate
    time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if time_elapsed > 1./frame_rate:
        prev = time.time()

        if label == "action_happened":
            count = count + 1
            if count == 3:
                methods.WmiSetBrightness(0, 0)
                methods.WmiSetBrightness(1, 100)
                methods.WmiSetBrightness(1, startpointbrightness)
```

The problem is that only the first line in the last if statement is processed
methods.WmiSetBrightness(0, 0)

Any help very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the first parameter to `WmiSetBrightness` a monitor id? You're using 0 in the first, and 1 in the next two...

Comment: the first statement is delay time in seconds
I changed all first statements to 0 and all to 1 or 0.1 but still only the first brightness modification is checked so my screen stays dark.
i tried print statements in between the last 3 lines and they all print but the second and third brightness modification lines are not excecuted

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmisetbrightness-method-in-class-wmimonitorbrightnessmethods

The WmiSetBrightness method accepts two parameters. The first one is time in seconds. Are you referring to 1 second in the first parameter?

Comment: Yea. even if i set them all to 0.1 or 1 my screen just stays on brightness level 0 (like specified in the first line)
print statements do print so the lines are processed but the brightness doesn't change even if i delete the third brightness modification line

Answer (score 0):

I asked the duck, but couldn't find any documentation that actually explains what the timeout parameter is for.

I did find this one project that appears (I do not run Windows, so I can't check) to successfully use the same call:

https://github.com/blackholeearth/Win10_BrightnessSlider/blob/master/Win10_BrightnessSlider/Form1.cs

```
foreach (ManagementObject mObj in objectCollection)
{
    mObj.InvokeMethod("WmiSetBrightness",
                      new Object[] { UInt32.MaxValue, targetBrightness });
    break;
}
```

Looping over the objects and always breaking is basically just calling the method on the first object in the list. I don't know if this is what you want.

I would suggest that you not try to do all three settings at the same time. Rather, you should build a state machine and update it on each pass through your outer loop:

```
def set_monitor_brightness(percent):
    """Under Windows, use WMI to set monitor brightness to a percentage of maximum"""
    timeout = 2 ** 32 - 1
    methods.WmiSetBrightness(timeout, percent)

Monitor_blink_state = None

def start_monitor_blink():
    """ Begin a 'monitor blink' to draw the user's attention"""

    global Monitor_blink_state
    Monitor_blink_state = "MIN"
    set_monitor_brightness(0)

def update_monitor_blink():
    """Update a monitor blink, if one is happening."""

    global Monitor_blink_state

    if Monitor_blink_state is None:
        return

    if Monitor_blink_state == "MIN":
        Monitor_blink_state = "MAX"
        set_monitor_brightness(100)
    elif Monitor_blink_state == "MAX":
        Monitor_blink_state = None
        set_monitor_brightness(startpointbrightness)

# ... later ...        

while True:
    update_monitor_blink()

    # rest of your code

        if count == 3:
            start_monitor_blink()
```

Comment: Your option (although it makes sense) gave me another error and i think it has to do with how openCV handles framerate and how python handles time...?
For example i added a line of time.sleep(0.1) between each of the 3 wmisetbrightness steps and it worked... but as soon as i increased it to time.sleep(0.2) it didn't work anymore... I then kept the time.sleep(0.2) and decreased the frame rate (meaning i increased the time between each iteration of the while loop) and it worked again... for the mockup i build he time.sleep solution is fine. THANK YOU THO!!!